# Driver transistor - what it is for?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt

I was looking for answer to following question: what for are driver transistors used? Can someon explain to me why circuit (simple class A amp) under this link does not work correctly:

[image: https://www.electro-tech-online.com/attachments/ceef-gif.27172/]

While this circuit works fine:

[image: Working A amp]

Original conversation is here: https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/how-to-connect-common-emitter-with-emitter-follower-to-speaker.90240/

Regarding the working circuit:
Why is the Q1 needed to drive Q2? Wouldnt it be enough to drive Q2 straight away from R1 R2 divider? If not, why? Thanks for help:)

Comment: As to why one doesn't work, it's nothing to do with the driver, but you may notice a slight difference in the output stage emitter resistances.

Comment: looks like it is working as designed to me

Comment: please explain what this means `does not work correctly`

Comment: As Brian points out, your 2nd circuit uses a ridiculously low value emitter resistor and a monster 2N3055. It's an insane circuit. But it can work after a fashion. Q2 pulls towards the + rail and R5 (still not so well) pulls towards ground, passively. The first circuit uses a 600 Ohm pull-down for the speaker and that will never really work. One doesn't even need to fret if the remainder of the circuit is right or wrong. The end-point of the 1st circuit can't work, so the rest can't either regardless.

Comment: @jonk 2nd circuit seems to work on simulation. R5 is low in order to receive all the current flowing from ground through R4 when voltage is on its lowest point. My question is, why it doesnt work with single transistor and when I add another one everything seems to be alright (even when I remove R3).

Comment: @EmKa It doesn't work with a single transistor because there isn't enough current gain for this "insanely bad" circuit (2nd one) with just one. You do get enough, with two in Darlington form. So the reason is obvious. But it is still a BAD circuit. R3 just sinks some current, so removing it doesn't prevent the circuit from working. It's still a BAD circuit. Measure the power supplied by V1. Compare that with the power in R4.

Comment: @jonk  Alright. The point is that I'm trying to do a class A amplifier with emitter follower on output stage. Maybe you have any suggestions on how to do it? Problem is that I can't find any schematics for a simple one on the internet... I know that it is insanely inefficient, but right now I'm doing it just for educational purposes.

Comment: @EmKa Are you serious? Let me pick an example to show you just how insane this is... Suppose you wanted to create a simple BJT emitter-follower class-A amplifier that would deliver \$10\:\textrm{W}\$ to a speaker. Roughly, you would dissipate something like \$170\:\textrm{W}\$ just for the quiescent power!! Are you prepared for this kind of BAD? Because that's where you are headed. It's very, very ugly. And you will need some seriously badass BJTs, power resistors, and heatsinks. Water-cooled heatsinks might help some.

Comment: If you are determined to build a class A amp, maybe take a look at the Pass Zen amp (designed by Nelson Pass). It is not a great amp but it is simple and other people have built them. You may want to read some books by Douglas Self, also.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you use multiple stages of transistor amplification ("driver" is just a particular case of this) whenever you cannot get the required power gain (voltage gain × current gain) in a single stage while simultaneously meeting other requirements such as input and output impedances as well as voltage and current swings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a emitter-follower \$10\:\textrm{W}\$ amplifier for you, using parts that can handle the current compliances with some residual current gain left over. They might even handle the dissipation if you can manage to apply yourself to all the details needed.

It's really simple. Just a current source plus the class-A emitter-follower output:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFQvyS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Sure. You'll need a couple of power supplies capable of almost \$10\:\textrm{A}\$ compliance current, each. Just a short shopping sprint away, though. No problem.

I figured I'd just use big TO-220 packaged devices all around for the BJTs. Their Early Effect is horrible, so I'm using a Wilson mirror in order to cope with it (four BJTs.) \$Q_1\$, \$Q_2\$, and \$Q_4\$ will be only about \$100\:\textrm{mW}\$ each. So those are easy. \$Q_3\$ and \$Q_6\$ will dissipate something like \$3-4\:\textrm{W}\$. So perhaps it is just starting to get a little warm now.

But \$Q_5\$ will be dissipating closer to \$40\:\textrm{W}\$!! That's within the maximum ratings listed on the datasheet, so there must be some method of handling that much dissipation.

And that's not the bad news!!

\$R_2\$ will be burning off something like \$120\:\textrm{W}\$!!! You will need a very serious resistor here! Search for the phrase, "non-inductive dummy load resistor," to see what these look like.

So, after tossing away about \$170\:\textrm{W}\$ in the amplifier circuit itself (not counting your speaker or the inefficiencies of your power supply rails), you will get a capability of driving that \$8\:\Omega\$ speaker with about \$10\:\textrm{W}\$.

Well. That's it. You can warm your hands on a very cold day as you listen to your music!

---

Or, perhaps you can see why you "can't find any schematics for a simple one on the internet" now? (Until now, that is.)

Of course, you will still need a voltage amplifier able to drive a \$10\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ load. This circuit is just the power driver for the speaker. It doesn't actually do any voltage amplification in the process. So you need something else to drive it with up to \$\pm 13\:\textrm{V}\$ swings. (Comes from \$\pm\sqrt{2\cdot P\cdot R}=\pm\sqrt{2\cdot 10\:\textrm{W}\cdot 8\:\Omega}\approx \pm 12.7\:\textrm{V}\$, plus a little because of the voltage gain being slightly less than 1.)

---

I think you can now see why it's worth the effort to turn this into a two-quadrant output driver. A little added complexity goes a long way.

Comment: Amplifiers for people who like their listening rooms small and warm.

Comment: @mkeith I suppose, if you already need an electric heater anyway, one might as well make it do something useful -- like be a class-A amplifier! Maybe all 1500 W heaters sold should be required by law to provide 100 W into an 8 Ohm load while they are heating up the room. Or else 800 volt plate voltage at 2 amps for a nice 4CX3000A CW keyed transmitter? (Vanguard II perhaps?) Might make it more fun buying an electric heater, then.